# do i need to explicitely add SET ANSI_NULLS ON in EntityFramework migration

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am writing migration for `stored procedure` with `EF 6`

```
string sqlQuery = @"
                            /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[GetSalesByLocation]    Script Date: 9/21/2016 8:32:36 AM ******/
                            SET ANSI_NULLS ON GO 

                            SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON GO

                            CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetSalesByLocation] 
                                                    @MerchantID bigint,
                                                    @LocationID bigint,
                                                    @AccountAccessID bigint,
                                                    @KioskID bigint,
                                                    @StartDate DATETIME,
                                                    @EndDate DATETIME
                            AS
                            BEGIN
                            .....
                            END
                            GO";
               Sql(sqlQuery);
```

when i try to run `Update-database` command i get below error

```
Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in a query batch.
Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
```

Also when i create `SP` without

```
 SET ANSI_NULLS ON GO                                 
 SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON GO
```

and open in SQL management studio i can see above statement getting added automatically.

So my question is if i am writing migration for stored procedure do i need to `set ansi null on explicitly?

Comment: can you show your `OnModelCreating()` method ?

Comment: Note: When writing something in T-SQL, `GO` should be on its own line. That said, `GO` isn't strictly T-SQL (see remarks here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx), so I'm not sure that you can even create a procedure like that. EDIT: As for the question at hand, it depends on your settings. It's not strictly necessary when you have the right settings, but it's probably good practice just in case.

Comment: @Sampath: there is nothing related to stored procedure

Comment: if you do so then you don't need to do it manually.it is automatic then.you can do it easily with `code first`.why you're not using it ?

Comment: @Sampath: my question is if i dont add those statement in migration will EF take care of it as default

Comment: yes,but you have to `map` it inside the `OnModelCreating()` method.

Comment: @Sampath: why i have to use map,if it is for calling i use
 db.Database.SqlQuery() method

Comment: it's manual no.if you need to generate it auto then you have to map it.

Answer (score 0):

SET ANSI_NULL and SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER outside the procedure affects SQL Server behaviour only for the session (so it will not be written in the stored procedure and it will not affect the stored procedure behaviour when the stored procedure will be run).
Also, SET ANSI_NULL ON is the default (try SELECT GETANSINULL() on SQMS) so you could omit it. You can also omit SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON (you are using `[]` to quote identifiers and not `"`).
If you need to run more statements on the same connection, in Management Studio you use GO, using ADO you can split them on different execution methods (so you will eventually see errors in the right place). Otherwise you can use `;` (in this case probably you can't use `;`).